# MismatchedInputException: Cannot deserialize instance of `java.lang.Integer` out of START_OBJECT token

Tags: java, xml, jackson, xml-parsing

I am trying to deserialise XML to Java Object using `XMLMapper` but I am facing `MistmactchInputException`.

XML:

```
<author>
 <id type="integer">1234</id>
 <name>Hello World</name>
</author>
```

Java Class:

```
public class MyObject {

 @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "id")
 private Integer id;

 @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "name")
 private String name;

 // Constructor, Getter, Setter
}
```

The problem is in the `id` xml tag, where `type="integer"` is mentioned. If I remove `type="integer"` it works perfectly fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just simply use `@JacksonXmlRootElement` annotation like:

```
    @JacksonXmlRootElement(localName = "id")
    @Data //for getters and setters
    public class Id {
    @JacksonXmlProperty(isAttribute=true)
    String type;
    @JacksonXmlText
    String text;
}
```

Your class should be like this:

```
public class MyObject {

 @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "id")
 private Id id;

 @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "name")
 private String name;

 // Constructor, Getter, Setter
}
```

Comment: I think there is a typo: `String int;` is supposed to be `String int id;`.

Comment: @LHCHIN not exactly but yes, there is a typo, thanks

Comment: @Ankit you are welcome. mark this answer as "useful".